# Is Fourier transform density preserving?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I know my question is not well-defined since Fourier domain and codomain are not the same, but one knows that they are actually homomorphic. Now what I mean by density preserving is as follows:

Consider a finite time, time series $X_t$. One can define finite time Fourier transform of this vector using the unitary circular matrix $F$  which its multiplication by $X$ returns the Fourier transform $\hat{X_\omega}$, i.e. 
$$\hat{X}=FX$$

since $F$ is unitary its obvious that $\det(A^{-1})$=1 and therefore if $X\sim p(x)$ then:

$$p_{\hat{X}}(\hat{X})=p(X)\det(dX/d\hat{X})=p_X(X).$$

Where $p_{\hat{X}}$ transformed density after applying Fourier transform. But in general Fourier transformation is not only for finite domain. The question is that whether this argument is true for infinite domain, i.e. when when $X$ is a process.

Comment: You are asking whether the Fourier transform preserves a measure... what measure?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I defined what I mean by preserving measure. It means, in case that density exists, the density over frequency domain is the same the density over time domain. For finite case I already wrote something which I beleive to be the proof

Comment: You have not introduced any measure on any infinite-dimensional space of functions.

Comment: I can introduce the density through Gaussian processes and indeed my question is about the density and nothing more.